# Cover photo changes not showing up in stream table query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am running the following query in FQL, which returns all the objects on my page's timeline, except the posts reflecting a change in cover photo.

SELECT type,permalink,post_id,message,actor_id,targeting,target_id,tagged_ids FROM stream WHERE source_id=xxx AND filter_key="owner" ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 1000

Is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong? If so, is there a way to get this information as well?